# Eloquent ORM: get generated SQL statement before executing it

Tags: php, eloquent

Does anybody know if it's possible to view the generated SQL statement before executing it?

I know I can get the Query log however that is after the statement has been executed. I am looking for a way to get/view the generated SQL statement before it has been executed.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `toSql()` method, i think this is what you want, but it will show you the query without any bindings

For example:

```
dd(User::where('id','=',5)->toSql())
```

will dump this:

```
select * from `users` where `id` = ?
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the sql by method `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toSql()`

```
Post::where('id', '>', 10)->toSql()
```

See demo https://implode.io/XDCq5G